# Autoit set console xy position

Tags: java, nsis

The java program need to be display for it to work, so may not use sw_hide or any hide command, how do I offset the position of the console out of the screen? Is NSIS is able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use nsExec::Exec instead of ExecWait. It will hide the console output. You can also use nsExec::ExecToLog to get the output printed directly into the NSIS log.

Other alternatives are the [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in) and [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) plug-ins. nsExec is bundled with NSIS.